# how to post an array with other Json values in an asp.net controller and iterate through that array

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have Users model class:

```
 public partial class Users
    {
        public Users()
        {
            Seasons = new HashSet<Seasons>();
            UserRoles = new HashSet<UserRoles>();
            UserSetting = new HashSet<UserSetting>();
        }
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EmailVerifiedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? MobileVerifiedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Seasons> Seasons { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserSetting> UserSetting { get; set; }
    }
```

Another class is:

```
public partial class UserRoles
    {
        public int? UserId { get; set; }
        public int? RoleId { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Roles Role { get; set; }
        public virtual Users User { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to send data to controller using post request here i have a user have  multiple roles so i have send data from post man like this

```
   {
     "FirstName":"Jignesh",
     "LastName":"Jignesh",
     "Email":"samjad@gmail.com",
     "Mobile":"99999999",
     "Password":"sss",
     "UserRoles[0]":1
   }
```

on the controller i  wrote the code like this.but UserRoles is an empty array

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostUsers(Users users)
   {
      foreach(var role in users.UserRoles)
           {
              var sql = "insert into 
              UserRoles(UserId,RoleId)values('{users.Id}','{role}')";
              Connection.ExecuteCommand(sql);
           }
    }
```

how to receive multiple RoleId in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
   {
     "FirstName":"Jignesh",
     "LastName":"Jignesh",
     "Email":"samjad@gmail.com",
     "Mobile":"99999999",
     "Password":"sss",
     "UserRoles": [
         { "Id": 1 },
         { "Id": 2 }  
      ]
   }
```